# Workday - Registering API Client - Terminology

Tags: workday-api

I want to use the Workday Rest API for Inter System communication

What is the difference between Register API Client and Register API Client for Integrations

Which one of those options should I use?

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official answer from Workday is as follows

You would use Register API Client when you want a user of your app/web site to be prompted to enter their authentication details. You can use Register API Client for Integrations when you don't want this human interaction.